# Diagnose and debug bind server configuration lookup with exit line

Tags: dns, bind, dig

I'm using dig with `dig someserver.com -p 53 @localhost` checking if my bind server do what it should.

However even if I have a rpz set up with a wildcard like

```
*.com A 127.0.0.1
```

most of .com replies correctly with 127.0.0.1 there are some domain.com that instead are resolved externally, let's say they strangely bypass the wildcard.

The configuration is very big with a ton of voices, so I'm wondering if there's another rule that instead forwards externally the request. I wonder... there's a command that could help me to understand which rule make bind act in that specific way? eg. this host is resolved this way cause the rule at line 2421 of that file ?

Comment: Simplify the configuration until it starts working. Then add in just enough to demonstrate the issue and post the resulting configuration file

Comment: That is a good suggestion but I was hoping to resolve it by searching.

Comment: We are very unlikely to be able to help you without information

Comment: @ChrisDavies I'm not asking a direct debug, I was asking if there's an utility or software associated in bind package that could provide explaining what rule is picked for the returning result.